# Lectura de una matriz en C++

Tags: c++, archivo, matriz

Buenas tardes a aquellos que me lean.

Tengo un pequeño problemilla leyendo ficheros y me gustaría saber si alguno de vosotros podría echarme una mano. El caso es el siguiente: tengo una matriz en un fichero (archivo .txt) de la siguiente manera:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 4 5 6 7 8
```

El caso es que el programa que tengo que diseñar me funciona al saber que dicha matriz es de 7 columnas. Sin embargo, mi programa ha de interpretar que el fichero tiene 2 filas y 7 columnas. Es decir, el fichero que me darán para leer será algo por el estilo siguiente:

```
2
7
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 4 5 6 7 8
```

donde el 2 de la primera fila sería el número de filas y el 7 de la segunda fila sería el número de columnas.

A continuación os adjunto el programa que he realizado para que me lea dicho fichero donde como podeis ver he definido N=2 y M=7 que es lo que el programa ha de interpretar.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> //para salida y entrada de datos por consola
#include <fstream>   //para salida y entrada de datos del fichero
#define N   2
#define M  7


using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    const char* nombre_fichero1 = "prueba.txt"; //nombre del fichero de la matriz

    FILE* fichero1;

    float matriz[N][M];
    int retval = 0; //valor de retorno

    fichero1 = fopen( nombre_fichero1, "r");

    if (fichero1 == NULL) {
        cout << endl << "Ha habido un error en la apertura del fichero, puede que no exista.";
    }
    else
    {
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (uint16_t j = 0; j < M; j++) {

                retval = fscanf(fichero1, "%f", &matriz[i][j]);

                if (feof(fichero1)) { //si llega al end of file
                    break; //sale del bucle interno
                }

             }
            if (feof(fichero1)) {
                break;
            }
        }


    fclose(fichero1);

    }
    system("PAUSE"); //para que no se cierre al terminar el programa
    return 0; //Debe devolver algo el main, lo que e de la gana
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano a todos.

Comment: Un poco offtopic. ¿Este no sería un ejercicio para resolver con memoria dinámica? Porque partes de una matriz de 2x7, pero qué pasaría si el fichero define la matriz con otro tamaño?

Comment: Es otra de las posibilidades qué había pensado y tal vez sea hasta mas fácil... No he de hacerlo con ningún metodo pero es ya más por curiosidad el saber como se haría siguiendo lo que ya había escrito.

Comment: A todo esto, ¿cual es el error o duda?

Comment: La duda es cómo podría modificar mi programa (qué añadir) para que con lo hecho sea capaz de leerme que los dos primeros numeros son las dimensiones de la matriz. No sé si me explico...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero de todo es que al estar en `C++` lo suyo es usar cabeceras y funciones propias. Así:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

deberían ser:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
```

Por otro lado, `C++` usa streams para leer/escribir archivos, así que mejor usarlos en lugar del `FILE` de `C`
Y es mejor práctica usar variables constantes en lugar de `DEFINE`, ya que estableces el tipo de las mismas.
Con todo esto, esta podría ser una solución. No es muy buena porque solo funciona si el fichero está bien estructurado como pones, ni hace comprobaciones, pero puede valer (tu propio código está mejor a la hora de hacer esas comprobaciones y deberías incorporarlo, pero eso es cosa tuya ;-) ):

```
#include <cstdlib>    
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream> //para salida y entrada de datos por consola
#include <fstream>   //para salida y entrada de datos del fichero


const int N = 2;
const int M = 7;


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float matriz[N][M];
    int retval = 0; //valor de retorno

    const char* nombre_fichero1 = "prueba.txt"; //nombre del fichero de la matriz
    ifstream fichero1 (nombre_fichero1);

    int filas, columnas;
    fichero1>>filas;
    fichero1>>columnas;

    cout<<"filas: "<<filas<<endl;
    cout<<"columnas: "<<columnas<<endl;

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<M;j++)
        {
            fichero1>>matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<M;j++)
        {
            cout<<"["<<matriz[i][j]<<"]";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    fichero1.close();
    return 0; //Debe devolver algo el main, lo que e de la gana
}
```

Como ves, por medio del operador `>>` mandamos vamos leyendo caracteres hasta que encontramos un espacio o salto de línea. Por eso en la primera lee el primer dígito, y luego el segundo. Ya tienes establecido el número de filas y columnas. Luego, al estar separados por espacios los elementos de la matriz, por medio de un doble bucle puedes ir leyendo caracter a caracter y alojarlo con el tipo correcto en cada elemento de la matriz.

Si además quieres que realmente el valor de los dos primeros dígitos del fichero de texto sirvan para dimensionar realmente la matriz, puedes usar memoria dinámica o un [contenedor](https://ccia.ugr.es/%7Ejfv/ed1/c++/cdrom4/paginaWeb/stl.htm):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream> //para salida y entrada de datos por consola
#include <fstream>   //para salida y entrada de datos del fichero


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int filas, columnas;
    const char* nombre_fichero1 = "prueba.txt"; //nombre del fichero de la matriz
    ifstream fichero1 (nombre_fichero1);
    fichero1>>filas;
    fichero1>>columnas;

    float** matriz;
    matriz = new float*[filas];
    for (int i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        matriz[i]=new float[columnas];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<columnas; j++)
        {
            fichero1>>matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<filas; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<columnas; j++)
        {
            cout<<"["<<matriz[i][j]<<"]";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    //liberar memoria MUY IMPORTANTE!!!
    for(int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
    {
        delete[] matriz[i];
    }
    delete[] matriz;
    fichero1.close();
    return 0; //Debe devolver algo el main, lo que e de la gana
```

Comment: Yo creo que las cabeceras cstdio y cstdlib directamente se pueden eliminar

Comment: Muchas gracias! La verdad que soy bastante novato en esto y he intentado hacerlo lo mejor que he podido leyendo algún manual y viendo algún video que otro pero tu respuesta sin duda me ha ayudado a resolver mi duda y entender mejor las cosas!

Comment: Si ves que te ha ayudado, márcala como válida al tick, para que otros puedan ver que es la respuesta más adecuada. ;-)